# How to connect to AWS RDS with SSL encryption from local?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, localhost, amazon-rds, ssh-tunnel

I want to connect to an AWS RDS via an EC2 from local.

I created a tunnel on my local machine:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -f -N -L 5432:RDS-Endpoint:5432 EC2-User@EC2-IP -v
```

This way can work:

```
psql -hlocalhost -Upostgres -p5432 -d postgres
```

It really connected to the RDS db.

But if use an another postgres user with SSL certificated

```
psql -hlocalhost -p5432 "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=rds-ca-2019-root.pem user=another_user dbname=my_db"
```

Caused this error:

```
psql: error: server certificate for "tf-xxx.rds.amazonaws.com" (and 2 other names) does not match host name "localhost"
```

If do it on EC2 server, it works well. On local, it seems that the certificate doesn't match `localhost`. Then how to set it correctly?

- [Connecting to your DB instance using IAM authentication from the command line: AWS CLI and psql client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.PostgreSQL.html)
- [Using SSL/TLS to encrypt a connection to a DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by specifying the 'hostaddr' as 127.0.0.1, but specifying the 'host' as whatever the real hostname is.

Comment: `psql -hostaddr127.0.0.1 -h[RDS-Endpoint] -p5432 "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=rds-ca-2019-root.pem user=another_user dbname=my_db"` - Error: `psql: error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out` RDS doesn't allow local IP.

Comment: You just specified two -h switches, the second of which overrided the first.  The hostaddr must be specified inside the connection string. There is no switch for it.

Comment: So can't use it with `psql`? I tried it still not work: `psql -h[RDS-Endpoint] -d "port=5432 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 sslmode=prefer sslrootcert=rds-ca-2019-root.pem user=another_user dbname=my_db"` Got `psql: error: FATAL:  role "another_user" does not exist`.

Comment: You have now progressed on to a completely different error, so in fact it did work. Now solve the new error.  Why did you change the name of the user relative to the one you already know works?

Comment: Actually I have connected the remote RDS by your advice by PgAdmin. Set `host` and `hostaddr` with different data. Now just want to make clear if I can connect via `psql` command. The `another_user` is a real user in remote db.

Comment: It is connecting the local postgres server so can't find the `another_user` role.

Comment: What happened to your tunnel?  You couldn't have a local postgresql server listening on that port if the tunnel were still listening on it.

Comment: I closed the local postgres server. It works! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using SSL encryptionin PostgreSQL with `sslmode=verify-full` is mutually exclusive with using an SSL tunnel, because the end point is effectively a "man in the middle".

Comment: Thank you. Then in this case, there isn't a way to do it for the user which under SSL encryption. The only way is to create a password for the user in order to use SSH tunnel, right?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand. You can have SSL encryption without using an SSL tunnel. On the other hand, if you use a tunnel, you are encrypted anyway.